# Using strptime to get UTC offset with separation between hours and minutes

Tags: python, datetime

I have a string like this `2018-04-03 02:59:59+00:00` and I need to use `strptime` to convert it to datetime.

However, looking at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), the `%z` (UTC offset) directive is `+HHMM`, but I need `+HH:MM`. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Python 3.7+

Ability to parse RFC 3339 dates and times was [added in Python 3.7](https://bugs.python.org/issue15873).

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> txt = "2018-04-03 02:59:59+00:00"
>>> fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z"
>>> datetime.strptime(txt, fmt)
datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 3, 2, 59, 59, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

In 3.7+, you could also use the simpler [`datetime.fromisoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) method:

```
>>> datetime.fromisoformat(txt)
datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 3, 2, 59, 59, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

#### Python < 3.7

It is not possible because of the colon character in the offset, i.e. `datetime.strptime` will parse an offset like `-0600` fine but not `-06:00`. So, choose one of the workarounds below:

- Pre-process the string to remove the colon from the offset
- Use a [`dateutil.parser`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) instead of `strptime`

Comment: `datetime.fromisoformat()` is exactly the functionality I was looking for. Works great, thank you.